# How to get text nodes from a parent node, and insert them in a div/span using jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="testoorig">
  <h3>Testo originale</h3>
  <div id="pag_10"></div>
  <br><span class="lineNumb"><b>1</b></span>
  <orig>d</orig> sometext sometext
  <span class="term" id="#formes">formes</span> sometext sometext <span class="term" id="#memoire">mémoire</span>;
  <mentioned><u>punirai</u></mentioned>,
  <mentioned><u>punir</u></mentioned>

  <!-- Next line (totally 31) -->

  <br><span class="lineNumb"><b>2</b></span> .....

</div>
<!-- #testoorig -->
```

I **can't** add anything in the DOM, because it's HTML produced by XSLT and for many reasons I **can't** edit it

I have this jQuery:

```
jQuery.fn.getParent = function (num) {
  var last = this[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    last = last.parentNode;
  }
  return jQuery(last);
};
  $(document).on("mouseover", ".lineNumb", function(g){
    target = $(this);
    target.css("background", "antiquewhite");
    arr = target.getParent(0).nextUntil(".lineNumb");

    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
      $(arr[i]).css("background", "antiquewhite");
    }
  });
```

So I would like that when you are mousing over each line, the entire line became "background: antiquewhite", in short words the line it has to be selected and marked.
Only the current line has to be marked (that's why I use nextUntil(".lineNumber"))

But, I only get stylized d (in `<orig>`), 1 (in `<b>`), formes, mèmoire(in `<span>`) punirai, punir (in `<mentioned>`)

It seems my code can't get "sometext", how can I get this and stylize it? (maybe wrapping it in a div or a span, something like this)

```js
jQuery.fn.getParent = function(num) {
  var last = this[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    last = last.parentNode;
  }
  return jQuery(last);
};

$(document).on("mouseover", ".lineNumb", function(g) {
  target = $(this);
  target.css("background", "pink");
  arr = target.getParent(0).nextUntil(".lineNumb");

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $(arr[i]).css("background", "lightblue");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="testoorig">
  <h3>Testo originale</h3>
  <div id="pag_10"></div>
  <br><span class="lineNumb"><b>1</b></span>
  <orig>d</orig> sometext sometext
  <span class="term" id="#formes">formes</span> sometext sometext <span class="term" id="#memoire">mémoire</span>;
  <mentioned><u>punirai</u></mentioned>,
  <mentioned><u>punir</u></mentioned>
  <br><span class="lineNumb"><b>2</b></span>
</div>
<!-- #testoorig -->


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Having a hard time understanding the actual question. Could you please reduce the info to only state the issue?

Comment: @0stone0 I just edited, you can run code snippet if you want. I would like that when overing with the mouse, also "sometext" (text nodes) became highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

Applying a background color to a collection of text-nodes and elements within one element (div) is not really possible as such. I therefore suggest, you manipulate the `innerHTML` of the `div.testoorig`: group all the elements you want to have a common background color together in one `div.row`. After that the hover-event can be easily assigned to these `.row` divs with a single `.on("mouseover mouseout",".row",function(ev){...})`:

```js
const divStart='<div class="row">',divEnd='</div>';
$(".testoorig")
 .html((_,html)=>{
   let arr=html.split("<br>");
   return arr.shift()+divStart+arr.join(divEnd+divStart)+divEnd;
 })
 .on("mouseover mouseout",".row",function(ev){
  $(this).toggleClass("hilite",ev.type=="mouseover");
 });
```

```css
.hilite {background-color:pink}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testoorig">
   <h3>Testo originale</h3>
   <div id="pag_10"></div>
   <br><span class="lineNumb"><b>1</b></span>
   <orig>d</orig>  first text sometext
   <span class="term" id="#formes">formes</span>
   sometext sometext
   <span class="term" id="#memoire">mémoire</span>;
   <mentioned><u>punirai</u></mentioned>, 
   <mentioned><u>punir</u></mentioned>

   <br><span class="lineNumb"><b>2</b></span>
   <orig>d</orig>  second text sometext
   <span class="term" id="#formes">formes</span>
   sometext sometext
   <span class="term" id="#memoire">mémoire</span>;
   <mentioned><u>punirai</u></mentioned>, 
   <mentioned><u>punir</u></mentioned>

   <br><span class="lineNumb"><b>3</b></span>
   <orig>d</orig>  third text sometext
   <span class="term" id="#formes">formes</span>
   sometext sometext
   <span class="term" id="#memoire">mémoire</span>;
   <mentioned><u>punirai</u></mentioned>, 
   <mentioned><u>punir</u></mentioned>
</div>
```

And here is a variation of @isherwood's approach that will respond to a mouseover on *any* of the elements of a section delimited by the `.lineNum` spans:

```js
$(function() {
 const $div=$('.testoorig');
 $div.contents().filter((i, c) =>c.nodeType===3).wrap('<span/>');
 $(".lineNumb",$div).each((i,el)=>{
  const $grp=$(el).nextUntil(".lineNumb").addBack();
  $grp.on("mouseover mouseout",ev=>
   $grp.toggleClass("hilite",ev.type=="mouseover")
  );
 });
});
```

```css
.hilite {background-color:pink}
```

```html
<div class="testoorig">
  <h3>Testo originale</h3>
  <div id="pag_10"></div>
  <br>

  <span class="lineNumb"><b>1</b></span>
  <orig>d</orig> sometext sometext
  <span class="term" id="#formes">formes</span> sometext sometext <span class="term" id="#memoire">mémoire</span>;
  <mentioned><u>punirai</u></mentioned>,
  <mentioned><u>punir</u></mentioned>
  <br>

  <span class="lineNumb"><b>2</b></span>
  <orig>d</orig> sometext sometext
  <span class="term" id="#formes2">formes</span> sometext sometext <span class="term" id="#memoire2">mémoire</span>;
  <mentioned><u>punirai</u></mentioned>,
  <mentioned><u>punir</u></mentioned>
  <br>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is functional, but it's cryptic as all get-out and seems to rely on a line break element, which could be fragile if the content changes at all. I do like the class toggle and considered that for my solution as well. In the end it seemed too cumbersome in my case.

Comment: It is up to OP to choose another separator for the `.split()` operation than `<br>` to make it more or less dependent on a particular HTML element. But I don't agree with @Isherwood that my solution is in any way "cryptic".

Comment: Of course not. You wrote it. :D This in particular took me, as an experienced JavaScript developer, a while to decipher: `arr.shift()+a+arr.join(b+a)+b`. Part of the problem is the one-letter variable names. Uggh.

Comment: Ok - we will probably not agree on this one. I guess in the end it is a matter of taste whether you prefer self-explanatory variable names and longer expressions OR shorter expression in which you will have to make sense of short variable names by looking at their definitions that incidentally can be found immediately before the actual expression. But, just to show, that I do take on board this type of constructive criticism: I have now renamed my variables. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, for a weird problem - a weird solution. To achieve highest performance  we can use background div with absolute positioning, and do all off the things  with css (we need just to calculate correct div height).

```js
window.onload = () => [...document.getElementsByClassName('lineNumb')].forEach(insertDivBefore);

function insertDivBefore(element) {
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  
  newDiv.className = 'fillDiv';
  newDiv.style.height = `${height}px`;
  document.getElementsByClassName('testoorig')[0].insertBefore(newDiv, element);
}
```

```css
.fillDiv {
  opacity: .2;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.fillDiv:hover {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="testoorig">
  <h3>Testo originale</h3>
  <div id="pag_10"></div>
  <br>

  <span class="lineNumb"><b>1</b></span>
  <orig>d</orig> sometext sometext
  <span class="term" id="#formes">formes</span> sometext sometext <span class="term" id="#memoire">mémoire</span>;
  <mentioned><u>punirai</u></mentioned>,
  <mentioned><u>punir</u></mentioned>
  <br>

  <span class="lineNumb"><b>2</b></span>
  <orig>d</orig> sometext sometext
  <span class="term" id="#formes2">formes</span> sometext sometext <span class="term" id="#memoire2">mémoire</span>;
  <mentioned><u>punirai</u></mentioned>,
  <mentioned><u>punir</u></mentioned>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First I'd wrap all text nodes in spans on document ready. Then I'd just use `nextUntil()` to grab all elements before the next line, along with `add()` to include the line number element.

Some notes:

- You were creating several global variables. Use `let` or `const` as appropriate.
- You were looping manually where jQuery already does it for you.
- You don't seem to need `g`, whatever that was.
- jQuery provides a [parent method](https://api.jquery.com/parent/). No need to write your own.
- I like single quotes in JavaScript, so that any HTML inside can use double quotes.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.testoorig').contents().each((i, c) => {
    // wrap text content nodes with a span
    if (c.nodeType === 3) {
      $(c).wrap('<span class="new-span" />');
    }
  });
});

$(document).on('mouseover', '.lineNumb', function() {
  const target = $(this);
  const lineEls = target.nextUntil('.lineNumb').add(target);

  lineEls.css('background', 'pink');
})
.on('mouseout', '.lineNumb', function() {
  $('.testoorig').children().css('background', '');
});
```

```html
<div class="testoorig">
  <h3>Testo originale</h3>
  <div id="pag_10"></div>
  <br>

  <span class="lineNumb"><b>1</b></span>
  <orig>d</orig> sometext sometext
  <span class="term" id="#formes">formes</span> sometext sometext <span class="term" id="#memoire">mémoire</span>;
  <mentioned><u>punirai</u></mentioned>,
  <mentioned><u>punir</u></mentioned>
  <br>

  <span class="lineNumb"><b>2</b></span>
  <orig>d</orig> sometext sometext
  <span class="term" id="#formes2">formes</span> sometext sometext <span class="term" id="#memoire2">mémoire</span>;
  <mentioned><u>punirai</u></mentioned>,
  <mentioned><u>punir</u></mentioned>
  <br>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This solution does work if you hover the mouse exactly over the `.lineNumb` element. Unfortunately, this element is relatively small in comparison to the whole section (OP calls it: "line") that will then change the background color. Would there be a way to make the _whole section_ sensitive to a mouseover/mouseout event?

Comment: What is the point of adding *class="new-span"* to the span elements in which you are wrapping the text nodes? What if the OP had a class "new-span" already defined? There seems to be nothing gained by this and a potential, albeit unlikely, problem that can arise. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Mostly to demonstrate what I mentioned about single and double quotes, but also to allow easy visualization of the outcome of the script in a document inspector.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest rewriting the blocks with javascript,
will be useful for any edit you'd need in the future.

So,

- get the block with a regex
- wrap the block with a tag

So you can work directly with HTML blocks, and you don't need the listener (you can use the CSS hover instead).

This solution uses some resources on page load but saves resources on page usage.

I chose to wrap outputs with "li" because it's a list

```js
// This regex extract all linesNum blocks, separated in an array, so it's easy to manipulate them
  // From lineNumb, included, to the second-mentioned, included.
  // If the input format will change will be easy to change the regex, it's quite intuitive
const rex=new RegExp(/<span class="lineNumb">(.+?)(?=<\/mentioned>)(.+?)(?=<\/mentioned>)/g);

function wrapOriginalText() {
  /// Exec thus code on page load, when text is already in the DOM
  const testoOrig = document.querySelector('.testoorig');
  
  const arr = testoOrig.innerHTML.toString().replace(/\n/g, '').match(rex);

  /// This will substitute testoorig, can add a classlist or an id
  const testoCopiato = document.createElement("div");
  const ul = document.createElement("ul");
  
  testoCopiato.classList.add('testocopiato');

  // wrap each line with li tags 
  arr.forEach(function(lineEl){

    /// create new block
    let el = document.createElement('li');

    /// insert HTML extracted with the regex
    el.innerHTML=lineEl;

    /// append the new div in the new parent element
    ul.appendChild(el);
  });
  
  // append the UL to the main div
  testoCopiato.appendChild(ul);
  
  // DOM was not modified yet, next 2 commands will write the DOM
  // Now remove the original testorig, 
  testoOrig.parentNode.removeChild(testoOrig);

  // and substitute with testocopiato 
  // I select "body" as a target, but you can chose where to put it
  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(testoCopiato);
 }
 
 wrapOriginalText();
```

```css
.testocopiato li:hover{
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="testoorig">
  <h3>Testo originale</h3>
  <div id="pag_10"></div>
  <br><span class="lineNumb"><b>1</b></span>
  <orig>d</orig> sometext sometext
  <span class="term" id="#formes">formes</span> sometext sometext <span class="term" id="#memoire">mémoire</span>;
  <mentioned><u>punirai</u></mentioned>,
  <mentioned><u>punir</u></mentioned>

  <!-- Next line (totally 31) -->

  <br><span class="lineNumb"><b>2</b></span>
  <orig>d</orig> some other text sometext
  <span class="term" id="#formes">formes</span> some new T some ... text <span class="term" id="#cesoir">ce soir</span>;
  <mentioned><u>dormirai</u></mentioned>,
  <mentioned><u>dormir</u></mentioned>

</div>
<!-- #testoorig -->
```

that's enough to highlight the entire row